# Shopify accessing back end controllers

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Is it possible to access back end of shopify?

I am thinking of doing some interfaces including some API rest calls, depending from information gotten I need to make logic so it would change depending on results.

Is it possible to access back end controllers, models, etc.. So I could handle the data before outputting it? I am little bit familiar with apps of shopify, however, did not see a way to achieve something I want. Correct me if I am wrong or lead me toward right road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot access the back end of Shopify. Instead, as a developer, you can request API access to a store, and code up response end points to requests from the admin. At one point ShopifyFD was a nifty Chrome based plugin that worked itself into the admin JS to offer up extra functionality, but you probably don't want to go there.

Comment: Okey thanks, one more question, can I add app return data on user account panel page? I will tweak it to work.

Comment: You can make a callback using the Proxy and return data to the customer account page.